# OSX freezes upon USB connect

Tags: macos, imac, usb, performance, migration

On a new (end 2012) iMac 21" with OSX ML as delivered I performed a migration from a backup drive that contained a *bootable* clone of the old machine, OSX 10.6.x, Users, Application, Libraries, etc, everything.

Migration process apparently OK. Two problems:

- I re-connect another external drive (1 TB Lacie) using USB. The computer runs its beach ball for ever. This disc is working properly on all other boxes in the house.  It is formatted for Mac OS, has only one partition,   and contains only data. Same behavior on all USB ports.
- The new box also freezes in (does not wake-up at all) after a long period of inactivity, presumably from deep sleep. Only solution, power cord OFF, not nice I know !

Performed:

- permission check and repair on *faulty* disc
- re-installed OS 10.8 using bootable hidden partition on new box
- de-installed Norton anti virus that was migrated by mistake from 10.6 partition

Has anyone another suggestion ? because I don't seem to be able to progress.

Comment: USB powered Lacie? If so, Directly connected, or thru a powered, or unpowered, hub?

Comment: thank you, *Wayfaring Stranger* to beg for precision: the Lacie disc has its own power supply, and the USB ports that were used were those natively installed on the new iMac. Besides: I'm not sure that the *USB-* and *wake-up induced* beach ball freezes share the same origin. We are maybe facing two separate issues.